I want to know on how to maintain center of gravity of a robot (IGV)
I am making a IGV (Inteligent ground vehicle) in the form of a cylinder with the base as a circle. I want to know whether my bot can climb a 15° gradient ramp or not.
Some specification of robot -

Max dimension (length: 3 feet, height: 6 feet, width: 4 feet).
payload 20 pounds
a battery (heavy)
three-wheel system (a castor wheel in front and two differential big wheel in the middle on either side of the circular base)
it also need to avid obstacles (eg traffic cone, drums etc.)


Homework?  What have you tried so far to determine if it'll tip?  What did your course work say about determining if a vehicle will tip on a slope?

Is that 15 supposed to be in degrees or some type of ratio? As for whether or not your robot can do what you want, I'd bet on not.

The standard way we find the cgz of a system is by a tilt test. Welcome to my world. In your case you need a list of components, where their centre of gravity is in 3d and their mass.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
